# Putting a variable into a DIV using HAML

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I'm trying to take an array value and assign it to a div class.

```
-values.each do |values|
    %p= values[0]
    %p= values[1]
```

Results in what you would expect. Proving that values[0] and values[1] contain data and they are working.

I fiddled around with it trying different things and this is as close as I can get:

```
-values.each do |values|
    - div = values[1]
    -.div= values[0]
```

Which then throws this error:

> undefined method `div=' for "day":String

And the string "day" is in values[1]

Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't know HAML so... but why not `%div`? Also, what's with `values.each do |values| ... values[0]`? Shouldn't that be `values.each do |val| ... val`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- values.each do |value|
  %div{ :class => value[1] }= value[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using this

```
-values.each do |values|
  %div= values[1]
  .div= values[0]
```

The first one will be a div and the second a div with class div.
The reason it says undefined method is because anything after the '-' is executed as ruby and you are basically doing this

```
values[1].day = values[0]
```

and there is no method day= for the string "day"

Comment: This doesn't work quite right. What I really want is something like .values[1]= values[0] where values[0] is put inside a dive class called .values[1].

Comment: I see, sorry didn't read every single word of the question :)

Comment: It's okay. I appreciate the attempt